# Schannel 36871 Error when sending emails from Database Mail - after upgrading to SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server-2016, database-mail, tls-1.2

I have recently upgraded from SQL Server 2014 ENT to 2016 ENT, and now I cannot send emails from Database Mail. I get the usual

```
The mail could not be sent to the recipients because of the mail server failure. 
    (Sending Mail using Account 1 (2018-09-07T13:19:55). 
Exception Message: Cannot send mails to mail server. 
(Failure sending mail.).
```

May or may not be related: I also get a system Error for SChannel

```
A fatal error occurred while creating an SSL client credential. The internal error state is 10013.
```

Googling around I enabled FIPS and this solved my database mail issue but (1) It broke Availability Groups eek! and (2) It is not recommended.

Any advice and information for understanding this is much appreciated.

I do have .Net Framework 3.5 SP1 installed - I have updated registry to force TLS 1.2. It looks like SQL Server is still trying to send emails with TLS 1.0

Comment: That message came from the SMTP server, not DBMail.  This is not a DBMail issue. The message indicates the recipient email address does not exist.  Check your email address  and check this too: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/aaced205-b0ec-4874-b440-8075dd74d8df/a-fatal-error-occurred-while-creating-an-ssl-client-credential-the-internal-error-state-is-10013?forum=exchangesvradmin

Comment: If that were the case, why would enabling FIPs solve the issue. Also I tried another non gmail mail server (sendgrid) same error.

Comment: Also, enabling FIPS is terrible advice.

Comment: Looks like when I enable TLS 1.0 it works. But it should be using TLS 1.2